# I'm getting ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a pageview inside it a custom widget in which I'm passing the `scrollController` after initialising. And also have some function to manipulate scrollController from that widget but whenever it reaches to run manipulation part it gives me this error.

`Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 109 pos 12: '_positions.length == 1': ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.`

**code**

```
class WeekView<T> extends StatefulWidget {
@override
  WeekViewState<T> createState() => WeekViewState<T>();
}
class WeekViewState<T> extends State<WeekView<T>> {
late ScrollController _scrollController;
late PageController _pageController;
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
_pageController = PageController(initialPage: _currentIndex);
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
  }

@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  if (widget.enableScrollToEvent) {
      if (widget.scrollToEvent == ScrollToEvent.currentTime &&
          _controller.events.last.endTime != null) {
        _controller.addListener(() {
          scrollToCurrentTime(_controller.events.last.endTime!);
        });
      } else {
        _controller.addListener(scrollToEvent);
      }
    }
}

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return PageView.builder(
                    itemCount: _totalWeeks,
                    controller: _pageController,
                    onPageChanged: _onPageChange,
                    itemBuilder: (_, index) {                      return InternalWeekViewPage<T>(
                     scrollController: _scrollController,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
}
```

the function,

```
void scrollToEvent() {
    if (_pageController.hasClients) {
      _pageController
          .animateToPage(
        _pageController.initialPage +
            ((_controller.events.last.date.getDayDifference(DateTime.now())) /
                    7)
                .floor(),
        curve: widget.pageTransitionCurve,
        duration: widget.pageTransitionDuration,
      )
          .then((value) {
        if (_scrollController.hasClients) {//<<<<<<<<<<< scrollController 
          if (_controller.events.last.endTime != null) { 
            _scrollController.animateTo(
              math.max(
                  _controller.events.last.endTime!.hour * _hourHeight -
                      _scrollController.position.viewportDimension +
                      _hourHeight,
                  0),
              duration: widget.scrollTransitionDuration,
              curve: widget.scrollToEventCurve,
            );
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

the custom widget,

```
class InternalWeekViewPage<T> extends StatelessWidget {
 const InternalWeekViewPage({
    required this.scrollController,
  });
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: scrollController,
                child:(...)
               ),);
}
}
```

Note-: I have removed some unnecessary part for more readability

**when I scroll manually and then I do the manipulation then it doesn't give me any error but doing it directly give me error.**

so why I'm getting this error even though I'm using it only in one place can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

From this code

```dart
  itemBuilder: (_, index) {      
                 return InternalWeekViewPage<T>(
                     scrollController: _scrollController,
                );
```

Item builder returning List of `InternalWeekViewPage` and having the same `_scrollController`.

Instead of passing `_scrollController`,  make `InternalWeekViewPage` statefullWidgte and create and initialize on `initState`.

Does it solve your issue?

Comment: I have to many changes in my code so i'm trying this

Comment: Also, you can generate a List of `_scrollController` and pass using `index`.